# returning 1 instead of true in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, boolean

I am trying to return one instead of true in python.

The code i am working on is:

```
delimiters = ( '()', '[]', '{}', "''", '""' )
esc = '\\'

def is_balanced(s, delimiters=delimiters, esc=esc):
    stack = []
    opening = tuple(str[0] for str in delimiters)
    closing = tuple(str[1] for str in delimiters)
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if len(stack) and stack[-1] == -1:
            stack.pop()
        elif c in esc:
            stack.append(-1)
        elif c in opening and (not len(stack) or opening[stack[-1]] != closing[stack[-1]]):
            stack.append(opening.index(c))
        elif c in closing:
            if len(stack) == 0 or closing.index(c) != stack[-1]:
                return False
            stack.pop()

    return len(stack) == 0

num_cases = raw_input()
num_cases = int(num_cases)
for num in range(num_cases):
    s = raw_input()
    print is_balanced(s)
```

It basically checks whether the string typed is balanced or not. If balanced, should return 1 and if not 0.

I tried this:

```
1
Test string
True
```

It returns true. I would like it to return 1. How do i do it?

Comment: `True` and `False` are subclasses of `int` with `True == 1` and `False == 0`.  In fact, you can do all of your normal arithmatic with `True` and `False`.  `1 + True` is a value expression (and evaluates to 2).  Similarly `1 + False` evaluates to 1 just as you would expect.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Alternatively you could cast your boolean to an int:

```
>>>myBoolean = True
>>>int(myBoolean)
1
>>>myBoolean = False
>>>int(myBoolean)
0
```

Answer (score 6):

Huh? You change the code:

Instead of

```
return False
```

write

```
return 0
```

and instead of

```
return len(stack) == 0
```

write

```
if len(stack) == 0:
  return 1
return 0
```

The latter 3-liner can be rewritten on a single line, but I chose the above for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

```
return 1 if len(stack) == 0 else 0
```

This concisely changes the return value of `is_balanced`, and is equivalent to:

```
if len(stack) == 0:
    return 1
else:
    return 0
```

Of course you could keep `is_balanced` unchanged and print (in similar notation):

```
1 if is_balanced(s) else 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
print +is_balanced(s)
```

instead.